# EmailBackEnd.authentication() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: django

that is the error I get when I tried to log in I don't really know if something is missing in my login code please help me review this code this is my

views.py

```
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Method Not Allowed</h2>")
    else:
        user = EmailBackEnd.authentication(
            request,
            username=request.POST.get("email"),
            password=request.POST.get("password"),
        )
        if user != None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse(
                "Email : "
                + request.POST.get("email")
                + "password : "
                + request.POST.get("password")
            )
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Login")


def GetUserDetails(request):
    if request.user != None:
        return HttpResponse(
            "User : " + request.email.user + "usertype : " + request.user.user_type
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Please login first")


def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponse("")
```

EmailBackEnd.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend


class EmailBackEnd(ModelBackend):
    def authentication(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from school_system.EmailBackEnd import EmailBackEnd

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.Login`your text`Page, name=""),
    path("get_user_details", views.GetUserDetails),
    path("logout_user", views.logout_user),
    path("user_login", views.user_login),
    path("", views.base, name=""),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

the error in your `EmailBackEnd.py`. The issue is with the `authentication` method. The `ModelBackend` class expects a method named `authenticate`, not `authentication`. Let's correct that:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class EmailBackEnd(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

Now, your authentication method should work as expected.

Also, make sure that your form in the login template is using the correct method (POST) and action ("/user_login/") to submit the login credentials. Double-check the HTML form in your login template.

Additionally, you may want to consider using Django's built-in LoginView for handling user authentication, as it simplifies the login process.